# PHP validate string date

Tags: php

I have 3 select boxes
How to validate date from string in PHP.
My date always format is Ex: "February 2 1978" and is come from client select boxes: Month, Day and Year, but also is possible to have another select boxes with differend strings.
So I need that string return false if is not date and return true for date

Thank you

Comment: You cant detect rather u can change into a format as u want using strtotime() or DateTime()

Comment: If the format is consistently like that, then `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j Y', $dateString);`... but detecting the date format is incredibly complex given the myriad of valid permutations, especially as it can be difficult to distinguish `d/m/Y` from `m/d/Y`

Comment: Sorry for my unclear english.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) Class.

```
<?php
$dt = 'February 2 1978';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d Y', $dt);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); //"prints" 02/02/1978
```

Instead of the `$dt = 'February 2 1978';` you will be passing your **`POST`** or **`GET`** parameter there. Such that it will be like `$dt = $_POST['dateselectedbytheuser'];`